# Oblique stripe using angularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to create such an oblique stripe using angularJS and Bootstrap?
[image: Oblique stripe]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that only using css:

HTML:

```
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="strip-container">
    <div class="strip">Sample Text</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle{
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #4B88CB;
}
.strip-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.strip{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4B88CB;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

[CHECK THE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/day1p2jn/)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that is right what I needed. I mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could for something like this

This solution has the advantage of having less "magic numbers" by having only the width of the stripe (could probably be fixed) and the top-offset in translate(50%, *offset*) as set values.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="stripe">
    <p>
      Sample Text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stripe
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(50%, 32px);
  transform-origin: 100% 0px;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/58mryy97/